# How do I free some bytes after moving a pointer?

Tags: c, memory, pointers

I do the following:

```
void * myFunction(void) {
    void *someBytes = malloc(1000);
    // fill someBytes

    //check the first three bytes (header)
    if(memcmp(someBytes, "OK+", 3) == 0) {
        // move the pointer (jump over the first three bytes)
        someBytes+=3
    }

    return someBytes;
}
```

How can the receiver free the malloced pointer?
Of course I could do a -3 on the pointer.

But is there a best practice for that case?
Is there a easy solution for still allowing in the receiver function to call `free(someBytes);`
Because `someBytes` could also held multiple megabytes I'd like to avoid memcpy (`malloc(1000)` is for the example only).

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is `realloc` -- that way, when you're through with the data you just read, you can continually resize the allocated bytes. Although, you've set us all up to fail by allocating 1000 bytes right away. From the sounds of it, you actually want to create an event oriented stream reader, made up of several circumstantial cases. Simply put: `tmp = read(3); if (memcmp(tmp, "OK+", 3) == 0) { free(tmp); tmp = read(997); /* more conditional testing here */ } else { free(tmp); }` -- only reading what you have to. (Except, instead of nesting tons of if's, it would be oop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way (unless you happen to know the exact offset). Best practice is to store a copy of the original pointer so you can later use it to free the memory.

```
void* myFunction(void) {
    void* someBytes = malloc(1000);
    void* pos = someBytes;
    // fill someBytes

    //check the first three bytes (header)
    if(memcmp(pos, "OK+", 3) == 0) {
        // move the pointer (jump over the first three bytes)
        pos+=3
    }

    return someBytes;
}
```

Comment: This won't compile. But then, so won't the OP's example. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not define a struct and have your function allocate and return a pointer to that?

```
struct MyStruct {
  PrivateHeader *header;
  UserData* data;
};
```

`PrivateHeader` is an opaque pointer to data that only `myFunction` knows how to access/manipulate; consumers of your function only know how to access/manipulate `data`.

Comment: Also thought that, but i cannot change the receiver's code. I need to check a three bytes header and return the buffer after the three bytes and ensure that the receiver can free the buffer. I think the only way is memcpy (or memmov)

Answer (score 0):

Can the receiver also create the buffer?  Why is myFunction allocating memory that it doesn't delete?

```
void* myFunction(void) {
  void* someBytes = malloc(1000);

  return someBytes;
}
```

is somewhat equivalent (functionally) to:

```
size_t myFunction(void* someBytes, size_t size) {
  // do something

  if(memcmp(someBytes, "OK+", 3) != 0) {
      return 0;  // didn't find nuthin'
  }

  return how_many_bytes_myFunction_put_in_the_buffer;
}


void myCaller(void)
{
  void* someBytes = malloc(1000);

  size_t result = myFunction(someBytes, 1000);

  // do something amazing

  free(someBytes);
}
```

Comment: Yeah. The design could be better... the function needs to create and return a malloc block (like a X_init function).

Comment: @JonasSchnelli, why?  Who deletes it?  Are you writing the myFunction?  Are you writing the function that calls myFunction?  If the answers to the last two questions are no and no, then there is nothing you can do AFAIK but return the pointer you malloc'ed.  You could try to do two reads, one to get the "OK+" and one to get the data.  Put the data in your malloc'ed block.  Throw away the data that contains "OK+" (this could be a simple 3 byte array on the stack).